# Is there a way to set the WebClientProtocol.Timeout default at the application level for a client application?

Tags: c#, web-services

The default timeout for a web service request is 100 seconds as noted on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.timeout.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WEB.SERVICES.PROTOCOLS.WEBCLIENTPROTOCOL%29;k%28WEBCLIENTPROTOCOL%29;k%28MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true).

Using this example:

```
 // build the request
 HelloWorldService.HelloWorldService service 
     = new HelloWorldService.HelloWorldService();

 HelloWorldService.echo request = new HelloWorldService.echo();
 request.arg0 = this.sound;

 // go get it!
 HelloWorldService.echoResponse response = service.echo(request);

 this.echo = response.@return;
```

If getting the response takes more than 100 seconds, it times out, as expected.  However, I have some slow queries on the server-side.  I *can* set the `service.Timout` property programmatically, but I would like to set it at the application level in the settings file and not have to worry about setting it on each call, as I will be connecting to a bunch of different web services.

Is there a way to do this?

Another option is to make this an asynchronous call, I suppose, but I have to wait for the data to go to my next steps either way, so a longer timeout *seems* to be the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you set the property in the constructor method  of webservice?

Easy and valid for any call.

```
public HelloWorldService()
{
   //some code...
   this.Timeout = Miliseconds;
}
```

Comment: As we add to HelloWorldService on the server side, we will be refreshing (and regenerating) the code in the client project. Your suggestion may be the easiest way for one service.  However, we're going to be adding other services as well (MyOtherService, YetAnotherService, etc.), so I would like to configure the timeout for all of them all at once, if possible.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: yeah, understand your problem now, but can't think any way to change the property via app.config or web.config. Maybe with a common inheritance to a intermediate class between service and WebClientprotocol but you will have the same problem as the other solution. Hope another user can help you :).

Comment: You answered the question, so I'm accepting and upvoting.  It definitely made me think.  My solution is another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Neonamu; there didn't seem to be a way to set this property.

I decided to go the asynchronous route instead.   It was very easy (only a couple more lines of code) and I think quite a bit more robust.  I'm not sure why I didn't go this route in the first place.

So the answer is to my problem is to call the service asynchronously.   The answer to the question asked is, "no".